# How to install Kiali on GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, istio, kiali

Is that have a way to install Kiali on GKE ?
I use GKE and install Istio with GKE option, so I cannot use helm to install Istio with Kiali.
Many articles use helm to install Istio with Kiali, I couldn't find a way to just install Kiali without Istio.

Answer (score 0):

Kiali [provides instructions to install the Kubernetes operator on top of Istio](https://www.kiali.io/documentation/getting-started/#_install_kiali_latest) if that's already installed.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use the Kiali scripts you will need to install prometheus on managed GKE/istio cluster; as explained here: https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#adding_prometheus. This is required for Kiali to get data about your cluster.

Comment: The link seems to have moved to https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/installing#enabling_prometheus_and_grafana. It's worth noting that Helm is indeed required for this workflow, and thus you should be able to enable Kiali the same way as Prometheus, e.g. `--set kiali.enabled=true`

Comment: @Ryota I think the link moved somewhere else again.

Comment: A quick scan found a new document https://cloud.google.com/service-mesh/docs/unified-install/options/third-party-integrations -- I didn't really check what has changed though, so what I said above may not be relevant anymore.

Answer (score 0):

just install the kiali by using Kiali Operator (https://kiali.io/documentation/v1.0/getting-started/#_install_the_kiali_operator)

By default kiali is going to connect to http://prometheus.istio-system:9090 and those service wouldn't be available on GKE with Istio Addon (https://cloud.google.com/istio/docs/istio-on-gke/release-notes#January_28_2019)

So, the solution is to patch the Kiali in order to connect to http://promsd.istio-system:9090:

```
kubectl -n kiali-operator patch kiali.kiali.io -p '{"spec": {"external_services": {"prometheus": {"url": "http://promsd.istio-system:9090"}}}}' kiali --type=merge
```

(the detailed discussion about this patch: https://github.com/kiali/kiali/issues/1174)